# SMTP issue when trying to submit a basic form

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, submit

I am sorry for so much code, but I am having an issue with this form.  I have tried every which way to configure it but I simply cannot get it to send.  All it needs to do is send an email with the message body, but every time I hit submit it just says error (which comes from the catch block).

This is in C# ASP.NET.

I am new to development and would appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance!

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string messageBody = "//numerous textboxes, dropdown lists, and checkboxes";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;

        try
        {
            // Prepare to and from e-mail addresses
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("info@kellersflowers.com");                
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(emailTextBox.Text);

            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add(toAddress);
            message.Subject = "Contact Form Email";
            message.Body = messageBody;

            // Server details
            smtp.Host = "email.goidp.com";
            // Credentials
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            // Send the email
            smtp.Send(message);                

            // Inform the user
            noticeLabel.Visible = true;
            noticeLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "block");
            //noticeLabel.Text = "E-mail sent";
            noticeLabel.Text = "Thank you, we have received your information and will be in touch soon.";

            // and clear the form
            fullNameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            companyTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
                 //many others, this is just to give the idea;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Error sending e-mail:<br/>\n" + ex.Message;
            Response.Redirect("estimate-error.html?error=1");
            errorLabel.Visible = true;
            errorLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "block");
            errorLabel.Text = "Error sending e-mail:<br/>\n" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //errorLabel.Text = "Error sending e-mail. Check required fields<br/>";
        //Response.Redirect("estimate-error.html?error=2");
        errorLabel.Visible = true;
        errorLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "block");
        errorLabel.Text = "Error sending e-mail. Check required fields<br/>";
    }
}
```

I am new to this site, so if I need to post more info I will.  Thank you!

Comment: It is just the generic error that is coming from the catch block.  It just says: "Error sending e-mail: Failed to send request"

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in the first line of the catch block and inspect the exception. It should contain detailed information, or maybe an inner exception

Comment: You could also change your error handler to display `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message` for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely, you're going to need to set some credentials for the SMTP object.

```
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@kellersflowers.com", "PasswordForEmail");
```

Hope that helps! Good Luck!